# How to slide elements together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/7vwcz/

So I'm trying to make a series of icons in a toolbar, represented here by little colored squares.

The first two, Contrast and Contrast2, will have popout sliders for controlling things. I'm just trying to get the icons to move smoothly out of the way for the slider, and then smoothly back into place. I have the animations set to a low speed right now so we can see what's going on. As you can see, they move erratically and not correctly-- you can see the action by clicking the reddish square.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 $('#contrastSlider').slider();
 $('#contrastSlider').hide()
 $('#contrast').click(function () {

     var cs = $('#contrastSlider'),
         w = cs.outerWidth(true);
     if (!cs.is(':visible')) {
         $('#about').css('margin-left', -w + 40);
         $('#contrast2').css('margin-left', -w);
         w = 0;
     }

     cs.toggle("slide", 2000);

     $('#contrast2').animate({
       'margin-left': -w
       }, 2000, function() {
         this.style.marginLeft = 0;
     });

     $('#about').animate({
         'margin-left': -w + 40
       }, 2000, function() {
         this.style.marginLeft = 0;
     });

 });
```

Comment: Updated the fiddle, wrong link before.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/JzRsG/

Comment: And back to the original position again, yes! How the hell...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7vwcz/5/

Comment: Although I really don't understand why the sliders are so wide when their width is mysteriously set to 0px

Comment: Padding. I'm updating that fiddle now.

Comment: @isherwood I was talking to Sven on that one-- your fiddle is also very helpful except that even at 0 width I can still see the slider, another thing I don't understand. It has to disappear entirely so that the icons are evenly spaced apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you close. As you can see, you don't have to work so hard. :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/7vwcz/10

```
var isOut = 0;

$('#contrast').click(function () {
    if (isOut == 0) {
        $('#contrastSlider').animate({width: 75, marginRight: '10px'}, 'slow');
        isOut = 1;
    } else {
        $('#contrastSlider').animate({width: 0, marginRight: '0'}, 'slow');
        isOut = 0;
    }
});
```

Here's a variant that doesn't rely on IDs and has a slider for each box (updated to use classes rather than vars): http://jsfiddle.net/7vwcz/14

```
$('.cube').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('out')) {
        $(this).removeClass('out').next('.flag').animate({width: 75, marginRight: '10px'}, 'slow');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('out').next('.flag').animate({width: 0, marginRight: '0'}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Based on your fiddle I'm ridiculously close to having this working but there's one odd bug-- look here, in this case, both of the first two now have working sliders, but after having clicked one, to activate the other you must click twice. Why on earth?? http://jsfiddle.net/7vwcz/13/

Comment: Oh, I forgot to create vars for each slider. They're all using the same one! I'm sure you can handle that, right?

Comment: You are making the same functions for each button and slider. Use classes and `next()` to remove all the redundancy! Sven's answer is much better in this. Oh I see it was already edited, nice hijack :P

Comment: My edits were done before Sven's answer was up. You can hover over any timestamp and get time to the second. No hijacking here. I did just edit again to use classes instead of vars, though.

Answer (score 2):

I will explain my comment more in this answer.

The html structure:

```
<ul>
    <li class="box">Menu</li> 
    <li class="slider">
    <li class="box">Menu</li> 
    <li class="slider">
    <li class="box">Menu</li> 
</ul>
```

An simple list with in it the menu boxes and slider bars. The flow is; the user clicks on an box, then the slider right to the box will slide out to `200px` and the rest will slide to `0px`.

The JS:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    // get the next li, it will be an slider because this is an .box li
    $slider = $(this).next();

    // animate all sliders to 0px width. so hiding all the sliders
    $('.slider').stop().animate({ width: '0px' }, 300);

    // do we have an slider? #about box doesn't 
    if($slider != null) {
        // the other sliders are still in the 'hiding' animation, but now we say to this slider to stop that animation and now to animate to 200px width 
        $slider.stop().animate({ width: '200px' }, 300);
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JzRsG/1/)